# 18.04: Oracle 18c Client Installation

Tags: 18.04, oracle

How to install the client in Ubuntu 18.04 for [Oracle 18c DB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/index.html).
in my environment i need to connect sqlplus through Ubuntu machine.
The Oracle server runs on CentOS 8.
Is it possible ?

Comment: So, you want to be able, on an Ubuntu 18.04 PC, to query with sqlplus, the Oracle database which runs on a CentOS 8 server, correct? And, you want to use an Oracle 18 client in Ubuntu to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html and download the [64-bit Linux client from Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html) then [perform the installation instructions.](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst) You will need to convert the RPM files to DEB files using [alien](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/alien.1p.html) and [these Ubuntu instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client). Installation detail follows:

Download the desired Instant Client ZIP files. All installations require a Basic or Basic Light package.

Unzip the packages into a single directory such as /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 that is accessible to your application. For example:

```
cd /opt/oracle      
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
```

The various packages install into subdirectories of /usr/lib/oracle, /usr/include/oracle, and /usr/share/oracle.

Install the operating system libaio package. For example, in Ubuntu, do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libaio` This is called libaio1 on some Linux distributions.

If Instant Client is the only Oracle Software installed on this system then update the runtime link path, for example:

```
sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 > \
      /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
  sudo ldconfig
```

Alternatively, set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable prior to running applications. For example:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The variable can optionally be added to configuration files such as ~/.bash_profile and to application configuration files such as /etc/sysconfig/httpd.

If you intend to co-locate optional Oracle configuration files such as tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora, ldap.ora, or oraaccess.xml with Instant Client, put them in the network/admin subdirectory. This needs to be created for 12.2 and earlier, for example:

```
mkdir -p /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/network/admin
```

This is the default Oracle configuration directory for applications linked with this Instant Client.

Alternatively, Oracle configuration files can be put in another, accessible directory. Then set the environment variable TNS_ADMIN to that directory name.

To use binaries such as sqlplus from the SQL*Plus package, unzip the package to the same directory as the Basic package and then update your PATH environment variable, for example:

```
export PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3:$PATH
```

Start your application.